# MySQL Count values from one column with selecting a value from another column

Tags: mysql

I have created a table as shown below:

> `CREATE TABLE myRecord(stu_name VARCHAR(50),gender VARCHAR(50),level VARCHAR(50));`
>   `INSERT INTO myRecord VALUES('John','Male','Pre-Primary');`
>   `INSERT INTO myRecord VALUES('Jane','Female','Year 1');`
>   `INSERT INTO myRecord VALUES('Sue','Female','Year 2');`

The expected result is supposed to be the following:

> `Male  | Female | Level`
>   `----------------------`
>   `1     |    0   | Pre-Primary`

But when I run the SQL below:

> `SELECT SUM(t.Male) AS Male,`
>   `SUM(t.Female) AS Female,`
>   `t.level`
>   `FROM`
>   `((SELECT SUM(gender='Male') as Male,`
>   `SUM(gender='Female') as Female,`
>   `CASE WHEN level='Pre-Primary'`
>   `THEN 'Pre-Primary'`
>   `END AS level`
>   `FROM myRecord`
>   `) t)`
>   `;`

The output is as the following:

> `Male  | Female | Level`
>   `----------------------`
>   `1     |    2   | Pre-Primary`

It also calculated Year 1 and Year 2. I only want it to calculate each gender of the level where level = 'Pre-Primary'. I've tried using GROUP BY level but it gave me the same result. I've also tried where but it gave me an error.

Is there any possible way to do that? I've been working on this for several days but I couldn't solve it and it's kinda disappointing. I hope someone can help on this.

Comment: why vendor & level has varchar(50) ? Hardly It should be 10 Chars

Comment: I don't know. I just put it randomly hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want a `where` clause:

```
SELECT SUM(gender = 'Male') AS Male, SUM(gender = 'Female') AS Female, level
FROM myRecord
WHERE level = 'Pre-Primary';
```

I don't see why a subquery would be necessary.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I don't know why I always think so hard like that. Thank you very much for your help :))